# Express localhost URLs in production for Electron app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, localhost, electron

I'm building an Electron app that uses an Express server to allow access to the local filesystem.

While developing locally, Express is using `localhost:3000` as the default url and all API interactions between the React frontend and the Express/Node server are being sent with `localhost` in the URL like so:

```
// Call getHistory in server.js
fetch(`http://localhost:3000/getHistory?file=${file}`)
.then((data) => data.json())
.then(function(data) {
    this.resizeImage(data.file);
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

What I'm not understanding is when it's time to package the app for production what do I do with the localhost urls?

I assume the app shouldn't run on port `:3000` as other applications may already be using this port.

Comment: One way to do is using a port finder such as https://github.com/indexzero/node-portfinder to dynamically allocate an open port, on allocation pass this information to the frontend (React) by using electron's Internal IPC Renderer.

Comment: Thank you, so it's perfectly acceptable to use localhost for a production app?

Comment: Depending on use case, its perfectly safe to use, but electron app can be decompiled and the source code can be extracted. It's recommended to keep proprietary techniques outside in a remote server, but if you are only looking to Save & Retrieve data, I don't believe it will be a problem.

Comment: As a side note, please be sure you are validating the host header in your express server. Otherwise your server is vulnerable to a DNS rebinding attack.